# Creating multiple POSTGRES partitions using a for....loop

Tags: postgresql

I've created a table that's partitioned by date ranges, (one partition per month) and the month is to be incorporated into the name of each partition.

I'd like to create a single partition for each month, going back several years.

This loop will *almost* do what I want

```
DO
$$
BEGIN 
  for v_counter in 1..12 by 1 loop
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE myTestTable_%1$s PARTITION OF myTestTable FOR VALUES FROM (''%2$s'') TO (''%3$s'') ', to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month','yyyymm'),to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month','yyyy-mm-01'),to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '0 month','yyyy-mm-01') );
  end loop;
end; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As it stands it'll successfully create a single partition for last month - and then generate 11 errors from trying to re-create the same partition multiple times.

I'm trying to incorporate the loop counter v_counter into the CREATE TABLE statement and use it define the date range for each partition. so that this bit

```
to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month','yyyymm')
```

on the 2nd pass becomes

```
to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '2 month','yyyymm')
```

and on the 3rd pass becomes....

```
to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '3 month','yyyymm')
```

etc etc.

So far all I've managed is to discover new ways of confusing myself.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Because the expression `to_char(CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month','yyyymm')` never changes in the loop. You want `to_char(CURRENT_DATE-make_interval(months => v_counter),'yyyymm')`

Comment: thanks horse - make that an answer, and I'll accept it!